# asp.net datalist nested with RadioButtonList on Postback are always NOT SELECTED

Tags: asp.net, postback, datalist, radiobuttonlist

I have a asp.net which contains a datalist and inside its itemtemplate it contains a radiobuttonlist

Here is my ASPX code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlQuestions" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" DataKeyField="ID" OnItemDataBound="dtlQuestions_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="q" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="dtlAnswers" runat="server" ValidationGroup='Bla' RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" CssClass="radioButtonList">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

In the code behind, I have a list of "Questons" which each item contains a list of Items.
I bind the questions to the Datalist, and each answer inside question is binded to the radioButtonList.

Here is the C# code:

```
protected void dtlQuestions_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    SurveyQuestion drv = e.Item.DataItem as SurveyQuestion;
    RadioButtonList RadioButtonList1 = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("dtlAnswers");
    foreach (QuestionAnswer a in drv.QuestionAnswers)
    {
        ListItem i = new ListItem();
        i.Text = a.Answer;
        i.Value = a.Answer;
        RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```

**Now my problem is when on a button click I want to go back and read every radiobutton and see if it is checked or not, I am able to loop through the radiobuttons but all are showing not selected.**

Here is the button submit click

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataList dtlQuestions = Page.FindControl("dtlQuestions") as DataList;

    foreach (DataListItem question in dtlQuestions.Items)
    {
        RadioButtonList rdList = question.FindControl("dtlAnswers") as RadioButtonList;

        foreach (ListItem answer in rdList.Items)
        {
            bool isSelected = answer.Selected;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show how actually you bind data to DataList?

Comment: Ohhhh I found it out. on Page_Loadi was adding a List of questons to the DataSource of the DataList.

My problem was I hadn't add a if(!Page.IsPostBack) to that part, so each time the button was clicked it was rebinding the data and losing my selected values. :)

Comment: :) It is probably most common problem in asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhhh I found it out. on Page_Loadi was adding a List of questons to the DataSource of the DataList. My problem was I hadn't add a if(!Page.IsPostBack) to that part, so each time the button was clicked it was rebinding the data and losing my selected values. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to share this problem . which help me to develop & to problem how to implement answer question . i try with nested repeater but problem radio button group. this article great help me. so after implement to face problem at save . above save code not working accurately . i fond solution and share with asp.net developer community .thanks

```
 count = 0;
        if (dtlQuestions.Items.Count > 0)
        {
    foreach (DataListItem li in dtlQuestions.Items)
            {       
                RadioButtonList rdList = li.FindControl("dtlAnswers") as RadioButtonList;
                HiddenField hnQuestionsid = (HiddenField)li.FindControl("hnQuestionsid");
                foreach (ListItem answer in rdList.Items)
                {
         bool isSelected = answer.Selected; if (isSelected){ int slval = Convert.ToInt32(answer.Value); InsertSurveyData(Convert.ToInt32(hnSurveyid.Value), Convert.ToInt32(hnQuestionsid.Value), Convert.ToInt32(slval));}}}}
```